# Help with Convergence of a series with sin and log

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I tried to figured it out if the follwing series converges or not

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(\frac{1}{n})}{\ln^2n}\ (-1)^{n}$$

I tried to show that $\sin(\frac{1}{n})$ is a monotonic but I'm not sure its in the right direction.

Comment: Series should start at $n=2.$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have $$\left\vert \frac{\sin(\frac{1}{n})}{\ln^2n}\ (-1)^{n}\right\vert \le \frac{1}{n \ln^2 n}$$ and $\sum \frac{1}{n \ln^2 n}$ converges. So you series converges absolutely.

Answer (score 2):

*Hint:* By the alternating series test, if the sequence $a_n$ is monotonically decreasing and $a_n \to 0$ then  $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n a_n$$ converges.

$\displaystyle a_n = \frac{\sin(1/n)}{\ln^2 n}$ meets those hypotheses as

- $\displaystyle \sin\left(1 \over n+1\right) < \sin\left(1 \over n\right)$ and $\ln^2 (n+1) > \ln^2 n$ implies $a_n$ is monotonically decreasing; and
- $\displaystyle 0 < \frac{\sin(1/n)}{\ln^2 n} < \frac{1}{\ln^2 n} \to 0$

Comment: don't you forget about monotone convergence to $0$ in alternating test ?